# PowerShell script to bulk migrate Shared Mailbox to Office 365 based on certain OU or .CSV file

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm running Hybrid Office 365 with Exchange 2013 SP1 CU15.

I am seeking a PowerShell command to migrate OnPremise Shared Mailbox to Office 365 based on specific OU or.CSV input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hi you can edit this file to your company**

```
$boxs = Get-Content your csv file
foreach ($box in $boxs){
    New-MoveRequest -Identity $box -Remote -RemoteHostName mail.domain.com -TargetDeliveryDomain domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com -RemoteCredential $cred

}
```